# Temporal database design, with a twist (live vs draft rows)

Tags: database-design

Not sure if/how I should be cross-posting this... But in case some follow DBA but not SO...

Is there a generally accepted means of managing live vs non-live rows in a row-version controlled environment? And if not, what have you tried and been reasonably successful with?

(Full details on the [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318317/temporal-database-design-with-a-twist-live-vs-draft-rows)).

---

I'm looking into implementing object-versioning with the added twist of needing to have both live and draft objects, and could use the insights from someone experience in this, as I'm beginning to wonder if it's even possible without potentially horrific hacks.

I'll break it down to posts with tags for the sake of the example, but my use-case is a bit more general (involving slowly changing dimensions - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension).

Suppose you've a posts table, a tags table, and a post2tag table:

```
posts (
 id
)

tags (
 id
)

post2tag (
 post_id fkey posts(id),
 tag_id fkey tags(id)
)
```

I'm in need of a couple of things:

1. Being able to show exactly how a post looked like at an arbitrary datetime, including for deleted rows.
2. Keep track of who is editing what, for a complete audit trail.
3. Needs a set of materialized views ("live" tables) for the sake of keeping referential integrity (i.e. logging should be transparent to the developers).
4. Needs to be appropriately fast for live *and* the latest draft rows.
5. Being able to have a draft post coexist with a live post.

I've been investigating various options. So far, the best I've come up with (without points #4/#5) looks a bit like the SCD type6-hybrid setup, but instead of having a current boolean there's a materialized view for the current row. For all intents and purposes, it looks like this:

```
posts (
 id pkey,
 public,
 created_at,
 updated_at,
 updated_by
)

post_revs (
 id,
 rev pkey,
 public,
 created_at,
 created_by,
 deleted_at
)

tags (
 id pkey,
 public,
 created_at,
 updated_at,
 updated_by
)


tag_revs (
 id,
 public,
 rev pkey,
 created_at,
 created_by,
 deleted_at
)

post2tag (
 post_id fkey posts(id),
 tag_id fkey tags(id),
 public,
 created_at,
 updated_at,
 updated_by
)

post2tag_revs (
 post_id,
 tag_id,
 post_rev fkey post_revs(rev), -- the rev when the relation started
 tag_rev fkey tag_revs(rev), -- the rev when the relation started
 public,
 created_at,
 created_by,
 deleted_at,
 pkey (post_rev, tag_rev)
)
```

I'm using pg_temporal to maintain indexes on period(created_at, deleted_at). And I keep the various tables in sync using triggers. Yada yada yada... I created the triggers that allow to cancel an edit to posts/tags in such a way that the draft gets stored into the revs without being published. It works great.

*Except* when I need to worry about draft-row related relations on post2tag. In that case, all hell breaks loose, and this hints to me that I've some kind of design problem in there. But I'm running out of ideas...

I've considered introducing data duplication (i.e. n post2tag rows introduced for each draft revision). This kind of works, but tends to be a lot slower than I'd like it to be.

I've considered introducing drafts tables for the "last draft", but this quickly tends to become very very ugly.

I've considered all sorts of flags...

So question: is there a generally accepted means of managing live vs non-live rows in a row-version controlled environment? And if not, what have you tried and been reasonably successful with?

Comment: You mention 'materialized views' in the SO post - and it seems you are using postgres. How are these implemented in a postgres context?

Comment: The good old way. :-) It's a physical table that is kept in sync with the rev tables using triggers on both sides. Changes in posts populate post_revs; changes in post_revs update posts if the row is live (they're denied if not).

Comment: Your comments on Bills answer indicate you are sensitive to performance considerations - is that right? Have you considered a transactional API instead of triggers?

Comment: Sort of. I'd like to be able to tinker with the data directly from SQL every now and then, so triggers get my preference to keep things in proper sync. I actually don't mind sacrificing some write speed, as long as I've reasonable read speed. :-) (What I currently have is acceptably fast for writes.)

Comment: @Jack: I think I nailed it. I added my own answer to the question, and would be curious to have your thoughts (if any) if you've a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross-posting the answer as well:

---

I think I nailed it. Basically, you add a (unique) draft field to the relevant tables, and you work on the drafts as if they were a new post/tag/etc.:

```
posts (
 id pkey,
 public,
 created_at stamptz,
 updated_at stamptz,
 updated_by int,
 draft int fkey posts (id) unique
)

post_revs (
 id,
 public,
 created_at,
 created_by,
 deleted_at,
 pkey (id, created_at)
)

tags (
 id pkey,
 public,
 created_at,
 updated_at,
 updated_by,
 draft fkey tags (id) unique
)


tag_revs (
 id,
 public,
 created_at,
 created_by,
 deleted_at,
 pkey (id, created_at)
)

post2tag (
 post_id fkey posts(id),
 tag_id fkey tags(id),
 public,
 created_at,
 updated_at,
 updated_by,
 pkey (post_id, tag_id)
)

post2tag_revs (
 post_id,
 tag_id,
 public,
 created_at,
 created_by,
 deleted_at,
 pkey (post_id, tag_id, created_at)
)
```